# Google Spreadsheet Script to run AFTER formula in cell has finished "Thinking..."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, formula, google-drive-api

I've done a lengthy search and much experimenting with code but couldn't find what I'm looking for. Maybe someone out there can kindly help?

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a complex formula in cell A1. Sometimes, the cell says "Thinking..." for a few seconds while the formula is working out a result.

I have a script 'myFunction()' which depends on the value in cell A1. It doesn't run properly if the cell says "Thinking...", so I am therefore trying to create another script which waits until the formula has finished 'Thinking', and then executes myFunction().

This is what I have so far:

```
function waitMyFunction () {      

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

    var range = s.getRange('A1:A1')  // range where I want to make sure 'Thinking' is done  
    var values = range.getValues();
    var string = values.toString();

    var loading = "Thinking...";

      while (string.search(loading) ==! 0); {
      (Utilities.sleep(10000));  // Wait for 10 seconds
}       
  myFunction();
};
```

The problem is, the script seems to wait for 10 seconds no matter what the value in cell A1 is. It waits even when the formula isn't 'Thinking'. I need this script to run fast, I can live with it taking 10 seconds the odd time the formula is thinking but  not every time!

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I have spent hours trying to work this one out. If anyone has any ideas, your help will be very much appreciated.

Many thanks for looking.

Comment: i don't want to build a complex function to test this, but does onEdit get called only after the Thinking... has finished? if it does then could you use that to your advantage?

Comment: @Jonathon, I agree. My intuition says that onEdit is only called after the formula has finished. So consider binding whatever script to the onEdit event, or write it in a function called onEdit().

Answer (score 0):

"loading" only gets evaluated once. If it is "Thinking ..." at the start it will always be that in while statement. So you need to get the value (NOT values) of the cell each time. 
You might like to check through the Javascript syntax for while and not-equals http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
If you want it to run faster then reduce the time delay/test more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be the same as: [Google SpreadSheets - When using a time trigger in code, some cells getting '#N/A' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374226/google-spreadsheets-when-using-a-time-trigger-in-code-some-cells-getting-n/19446695?noredirect=1#comment28886210_19446695)

Side note, I suspect you also want to remove the ";"

```
while (string.search(loading) ==! 0)  ;
                                      ^
```