# Google SpreadSheets - When using a time trigger in code, some cells getting '#N/A' value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I've created a Google spreadsheet with imported data on one cell, extracting specific string to another cell and pasting the data in a table with a trigger for every 2 hours.
Now everything works perfectly when running the script manually but when logged out and waiting for the cells to fill, sometimes the pasted cell getting "#N/A" value.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
function PasteV(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var timestamp= sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  var sale= sheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var rent= sheet.getRange("J1").getValue();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp, rent, sale]);
}
```

Again when running manually countless times - no problem.
I'll appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried your code in a test sheet and got no error... try by replacing getActiveSpreadsheet with openById('your SS ID')

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I tried replacing with openById but still some of the cells getting "#N/A", it's inconsistent.All is working great when logged and running the script manually. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#N/A is caused by using a custom function. There is an issue for it on the google-apps-script issue tracker, see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1131

Sounds like the same bug, your description sounds the same.

Comment: Thanks eddyparkinson. Seems this workaround is working for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614895/cells-containing-custom-functions-return-nan-when-spreadsheet-is-not-open-a/17371490#17371490

Comment: yes, the workaround works well, but take care as every once in a while I still get a script time out.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that... any idea's on improving this workaround script?

Comment: I got round the problem by not depending on custom functions. I.e. made my code work even if the custom function did not execute. Not an option for everyone, but worked for me.